# Which word is more appropriate for the sentence

Tags: grammar

The ploughed field is ready for __,  I was given two selections, sowing and seeding, I chosed "seeding",but my teacher said it is"sowing",but she doesnt tell me why, so please tell me which one is correct.It seems the two words have similar meanings.

Comment: Seriously??  It was "sewing" and not "sowing"???

Comment: "Field ready for sowing" is slightly more common than "field ready for seeding", but both are used.

Comment: In my experience lawns are seeded, fields are sown.

Comment: @Jim - In my experience, "sowing" implies "broadcasting" the seed, while "seeding" carries no such implication, and would be more appropriate for, eg, placing seeds in a row.

Comment: @HotLicks - Interesting.  I feel like it’s the opposite.  Lawns are seeded by broadcasting, fields are sown in neat rows with evenly placed seed deposits.